# Haskell error: Couldn't match type ‘a’ with ‘Double’

Tags: haskell

I am writing a Haskell code to find a list of the k nearest neighbours, in distance order, according to metric d to point p in the list xs of points. My code is below

```
import Data.List
import Data.Function

type Point a = (a,a)
type Metric a = (Point a) -> (Point a) -> Double

neighbours :: Int -> Metric a -> Point a -> [Point a] -> [Point a]
neighbours k calDistance p [] = []
neighbours k calDistance p ps
 | k < 0     = error "k cannot be negative"
 | otherwise = take k (neighbours' (sortBy (compare `on` snd) [ (poi,dis) | (poi,dis) <- points p ps]))

neighbours' :: [(Point a, Double)] -> [Point a]
neighbours' xs = [ x | (x,y)<-xs]

points :: Point a -> [Point a] -> [(Point a, Double)]
points _ [] = []
points p1 (p2:px) = (p2,(calDistance p1 p2)): points p1 px

calDistance :: Metric Double
calDistance (x1,y1) (x2,y2) = sqrt((x1-x2)**2 + (y1-y2)**2)
```

The error is

```
    • Couldn't match type ‘a’ with ‘Double’
      ‘a’ is a rigid type variable bound by
        the type signature for:
          points :: forall a. Point a -> [Point a] -> [(Point a, Double)]
        at A4.hs:27:1-53
      Expected type: Point Double
        Actual type: Point a
    • In the first argument of ‘calDistance’, namely ‘p1’
      In the expression: (calDistance p1 p2)
      In the first argument of ‘(:)’, namely ‘(p2, (calDistance p1 p2))’
    • Relevant bindings include
        px :: [Point a] (bound at A4.hs:29:15)
        p2 :: Point a (bound at A4.hs:29:12)
        p1 :: Point a (bound at A4.hs:29:8)
        points :: Point a -> [Point a] -> [(Point a, Double)]
          (bound at A4.hs:28:1)
   |
29 | points p1 (p2:px) = (p2,(calDistance p1 p2)): points p1 px
   |
```

However, if I change 'Metric Double' to 'Double a' there is also a compile error: Couldn't match expected type ‘Double’ with actual type ‘a’. Please can someone tell me how to solve it?

Answer (score 2):

See in the implementation of

```
points :: Point a -> [Point a] -> [(Point a, Double)]
```

you call

```
calDistance :: Metric Double
```

This means, that `a` has to be `Double`, as what should happen if someone called `points` with a value of type `Point Int` as the first argument? How should `calDistance` handle that, as it can only handle values of `Point Double`?

The error tells you, that `calDistance` was called with a value of type `Point a`, where `a` could be any type. And that doesn't match as `calDistance` expects a `Point Double` as its first argument.

Comment: Further `a` will be *too* general; not all types support `sqrt` and `**`. The correct signature (which GHCi can infer for you, if you omit the signature entirely), is `Floating a => Metric a`.